# Вывести 2 столбика по разным значениям WHERE SQL

Tags: sql

[image: Таблица]

Прошу помощи с составление запроса. Из таблицы результатов взвешивания юношей, мне нужно вывести их результаты за текущий период с появлением нового столбца "Вес в прошлом периоде".

Пробовал решить через Count - вывел столбики, но получил нули, выводил через вложенный select - тоже получил нули.

Comment: https://www.windowfunctions.com/?

Comment: что такое "Вес в прошлом периоде" - любая запись, где period < 10.2020 или именно 09.2020?

Comment: период датой сделайте на начало месяца и самоджойн на соответствующее условие напишите

Comment: Вес в прошлом периоде означает вес в прошлом месяце, в данном случае в сентябре 2020

Comment: @Rickie тогда это - обычный left join. `select t1.*, t2.weight_now as weight_before from table t1 join table t2 on (t2.id = t1.id and t2.period = PERIOD - '1month') where t1.period = PERIOD `

Comment: 1) я правильно понял что t2 это псевдоним основной таблицы для join'a ?                 2) И что такое t2.period = PERIOD - '1month' если данные по периодам представлены строкой 09.2020, 10.2020

Comment: 1) Да. 2) Это значит, что Вы должны обеспечить проверку указанной разности в рамках синтаксиса Вашей СУБД.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало. Не могу получить NULL при пустых значениях веса, как у Миши и Паши. Строки, в которых не хватает данных выкидываются из запроса

Comment: Помог LEFT JOIN, все заработало как нужно. Спасибо!

Comment: ну и здорово. можешь сам оформить ответ

Answer (score 1):

select t1.*, t2.weight_now as weight_before from table t1 left join table t2 on (t2.id = t1.id and t2.period = PERIOD - '1month') where t1.period = PERIOD

Где:

1. table t2 - это псевдоним основной таблицы для join'a,
2. t2.period = PERIOD - '1month' - это проверка указанной разности в рамках синтаксиса данной СУБД